# Using stage_block API to upload file chunk is so slow when executing under Uwsgi request in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, azure-blob-storage, uwsgi

I am using python 2.7.18 with azure-storage-blob==12.3.2 and Django to implement file upload with small chunk, when calling stage_block API in interactive mode directly each chunk request takes less than a second. While under Uwsgi  request , it was so slow and each chunk data need almost 90 seconds to complete. What are the possible reasons?

```
# directly calling
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import base64
import os
    
container = "test"
blob_name = "test"
blob = BlobClient(account_url=******,
                  container_name=container, blob_name=blob_name)
chunk_size = chunk*1024*1024
block_ids = []

index = 0
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(chunk_size)
        if data:
            length = len(data)
            block_id = base64.encodestring(str(index)).strip()
            blob.stage_block(block_id, data)
            index += 1
        else:
            break
resp = blob.commit_block_list(block_ids)

# Django request，uwsigi wrapped
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container = ContainerClient(account_url=********,
                            container_name="test")
def process_chunk(request):
    import base64
    id = request.GET['id'] 
    idx = request.GET['idx'] 
    data = base64.b64decode(request.POST['data'])
    blob = container.get_blob_client(id)
    block_id = base64.encodestring(str(idx)).strip()
    try:
        blob.stage_block(block_id, data)
        return HttpResponse(status=200, content="ok", content_type='text/plain')
    except Exception, ex:
        import traceback
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        return HttpResponse(status=500, content="failure", content_type='text/plain')
            
The uwsgi config is like below:
    
master          = true
single-interpreter = true
processes       = 8
enable-threads  = true
threads         = 20
socket          = /tmp/instance.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
listen          = 8192
harakiri        = 90
vacuum          = true
buffer-size     = 65536
```

I suspect that it is related to the obtained blob instance, but even if I only have one chunk (a very small file), the result is still the same.

Comment: 90 seconds - that sounds like the amount of time it would take for something to timeout... like a name lookup or something. But, you didn't mention any exceptions being raised. Were there no exceptions?   Things to try: do the whole process by hand from a python console, see what you learn.  Also, add some logging so you can see which step is the one adding the long delay.  Another possible source of slowdown: throttling.  Is it possible that Azure is throttling your client?

Comment: From python console, echa chunk takes less than 1 seconds. No exceptions, the chunk data is finally success although it takes almost 90 seconds. How can I determine if it was caused by throttling

Comment: 1) try it by hand. run the code interactively and get some experience with it.  2) read the details of the Azure API.  with any 3rd party API, there will tend to be some usage limits.  If you are free tier, they might hit early in usage.  In any case, throttling is unlikely to be your issue but it is good to be aware of it.  You can see some detail here, for instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling